# itext image field in fillable form

Tags: java, pdf, itext

in itext 2 the below code worked well, in itext 5 it fail.
does anyone have a sample of how to add an image to an image field on a PDF?

This is my code...

```
public static void atsSetFieldImage(AcroFields form, PdfStamper stamper, String fieldName, Image img) 
{
    try 
    {
        float[] photograph = form.getFieldPositions(fieldName);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(photograph[1]
                           , photograph[2]
                           , photograph[3]
                           , photograph[4]);

        //Image img = Image.getInstance(imageName);
              image1.scaleToFit(rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
              image1.setAbsolutePosition(
                                    photograph[1] + (rect.getWidth() - image1.getScaledWidth()) / 2
                                  , photograph[2] + (rect.getHeight() - image1.getScaledHeight()) / 2);

        PdfContentByte cb = stamper.getOverContent((int)photograph[0]);
                       cb.addImage(image1);

    }
    catch(Exception e) 
    {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How to add an image to an acroForm field:

```
Rectangle rect = form.getFieldPositions(fieldName)[0].position;
int page = form.getFieldPositions(fieldName)[0].page;
//Scale it
image1.scaleAbsolute(rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
//Position it
img.setAbsolutePosition(rect.getLeft(), rect.getBottom());
//Add it to the correct page
stamper.getOverContent(page).addImage(img);
```

Comment: Instead of using a array of float values, you now get a FieldPosition object that gives you a Rectangle and a page number. This is much better than what we had before.

Comment: I tried this and form.getFieldPositions errors and says that it needs to be a list, I tried converting it to a list and more errors come.

Comment: If it matters, I am using iText 5.3.4 and this is the exact error that I get "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to List"